# Optional form fields in spring-mvc liferay portlet application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, liferay

I have a big form with a lot of date fields and int fields
my action phase methos is like this:

```
public void createCamapign(WebRequest request,ActionResponse response ,
        Model model, @ModelAttribute("searchForm") CreateCampaignForm form) throws Exception{
```

where the form is my wrapper bean
anyway if i dont fill all the fields in the rendered form my application crashed with this error

> [org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet] - Handler execution resulted in exception - forwarding to resolved error view
>   org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
>   Field error in object 'searchForm' on field 'activationDate': rejected value []; codes [typeMismatch.searchForm.activationDate,typeMismatch.activationDate,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [searchForm.activationDate,activationDate]; arguments []; default message [activationDate]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'activationDate'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Date] for property 'activationDate': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]

how or where do i specify that these fields are optional
by the way in the case of int fields i kinda resolved it by using Integer class, but i dont want to do the same with Date type attributes

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your problem correctly. I am not an expert in Spring. 
Just a suggestion, like can you make use of dependency check and @Required annotation to make a few fields necessary and other ignorable.

Comment: two problems one it seems that the default value is required, second i didnt managed to connect hibernate validations (like @required) to spring -  MVC

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put the [`DateTimeFormat`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) annotation on you date fields, like this:

```
 @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/mm/yyyy")  // put any pattern you want
 private Date myDate;
```

Note: If you are using a version of Spring older than 3.2, you need to add **[joda](http://sourceforge.net/projects/joda-time/files/joda-time/2.3/)** date library to your project classpath

Comment: the problem is not with the format , the problem is that this field is optional so when the user doesnt fill it my app crashes.

Comment: the exception you have showed "Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Date] for property 'activationDate': no matching editors or conversion strategy found" means that the binder is searching for some converter or editor to convert the date string coming from the form to Date object

Comment: You could read more about Editor and Converter here http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Comment: the exception is raised because date type attributes cannot receive null- which is what is happeing when user posts the form without filling this camp (because its optional)

Comment: Does this happen with any other than the Date class?. Also, Did you tried the solution?